# How to get the DDL for an index organized table (IOT)

Tags: oracle, indexing

I am trying to get DDL for IOT tables in Oracle. Could you please suggest how this could be done using dbms_metadata.get_ddl ?

Answer (score 1):

Minimal test case:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_t PRIMARY KEY,
  c1 VARCHAR2(20)
) ORGANIZATION INDEX;
```

Get DDL:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'T') FROM dual;
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE "SO"."T" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "C1" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_T" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  ORGANIZATION INDEX NOCOMPRESS PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" 
 PCTTHRESHOLD 50"
```